# WinSCP with tabs or alternative

Tags: tabs, winscp

This has been bugging me for a while now. I really miss tabs in WinSCP, because I always have to backtrack back and forward between folders on the same server.
Everytime I do a google search if tabs are implemented already I come to [this thread](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6094), which isn't very helpful. And I can't find anything else.

So does anybody know if there is a fork/patch or something that would bring tab support to WinSCP, or if there is some good alternative to WinSCP that has tab support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for SCP functionality, you can take a look at FileZilla. It allows SCP connections and tabbed windows.

Get it [here](http://filezilla-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP supports [session tabs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_tabs) already too:

[image: Tabs screenshot]